# Find the probability that in a class of 12 pupils fewer than half of them have errors in their marking.

Tags: probability

> The number of mistakes a teacher makes whilst marking homework has a Poisson distribution with a mean of 1.6 errors per piece of homework.
>
> Find the probability that in a class of 12 pupils fewer than half of them have errors in their marking.

I found $P(x\leq 5)$ where the mean was $1.6\cdot 12=19.2$. This was on the $-4$ order of magnitude. The answer provided $0.00413$. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're not interpreting the question correctly.

Each student has a probability $p$ which they have no errors, which you can compute using the Poisson process.

After that, the number of students with errors follows a binomial random variable $X\sim B(12,1-p)$.

Comment: How do I calculate p?

Comment: Use $P(Y = 0)$ where $Y\sim Po(1.6)$.

Comment: I got $P(Y=0) = 0.201896518$ and $Binomcdf(12, P(y=0), 7) = 0.999...$ with $1 -$ that giving something on the order of $-4$

Comment: My apologies, perhaps my original answer wasn't as clear as I'd hoped. Try the binomial with $1-p$ for $P(X\leq 5)$, since errors are what you're looking for.

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect the above.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since this was posted but for future students:
mean=1.6
The probability that the teacher will make at least one error: 
X~Po(1.6, x>/=1) 
= 1- Po(1.6, 0)
=0.798
Thats the probability that a student will receive a paper with at least one error.
Binomially, your number of trials (students) is 12, your success rate is 0.798, and your x is 5 (<(half of 12) = <6, or less than or equal to 5). Therefore,

X~B(12, 0.798, 5) = 0.00414

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.